# Conditional visibility of combo box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a page that checks whether the ROLE_ID = 3 or not and if it is 3 then

```
        if ((Int32.Parse(Session["RoleID"].ToString()) == 3))

        {

            cmbempList.Visible = false;

        }
```

Now I want to check that the user with ROLE_ID = 3 is a mentor or not and if he is a mentor then the cmbempList would be visible to him.

```
  public bool CheckMentorAccess()

    {

        bool blnAllow = false;

        try
        {
            string strSelectMentorQuery = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MLL.LED_ID) FROM M_USER_DETAILS MUD INNER JOIN M_LEADERLED MLL "
                + "ON MLL.LED_ID = MUD.PK_ID WHERE MLL.LEADER_ID = '" + Session["UserID"].ToString()
                + "' AND MUD.ACTIVE = 1 AND MLL.START_DATE <= Getdate() AND"
                + " MLL.END_DATE > Getdate()";

            int intNoOfMembers = Convert.ToInt32(cSQLHelper.myExecuteScalar(strSelectMentorQuery));

            if (intNoOfMembers > 0)
            {
                blnAllow = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
            blnAllow = false;
        }

        // Return the value
        return blnAllow;
    }
```

if this function returns true, and the ROLE_ID = 3 then the cmbempList would be visible to him.

Can anybody help me??

Comment: @OP - you should consider modifying your SQL to use parameterized queries, or else stored procedures, to reduce risk SQL injection.  In the example you provided, you are subject to injection if `Session["UserID"]` happens to be set to a malicious string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the problem then , you have the CheckMentorAccess() function which returns true if logged in user is Mentor and you have Stored RULEID in the session variable so  now your business rule says that

**Now I want to check that the user with ROLE_ID = 3 is a mentor or not and if he is a mentor then the cmbempList would be visible to him**.

if you analyze this sentence , it contains two statements

1- User Must Have a RoleId = 3

2- User Must be mentor.

so if you want to combine these statements , it will become User must have role_id = 3   and    user must be mentor.

so converting above condition in c#  code

```
int roleId 

if(int.TryParse(Session["RoleID"].ToString(),out roleId))
 {
   cmbempList.Visible = ((roleId == 3) && CheckMentorAccess());
 }
```